# Execute inline javascript in wordpress after page fully loaded

Tags: plugins, javascript, cache

I am trying to find out the time it takes to fully load a page in wordpress using javascript.My JavaScript code is inline.I am using `wp_print_scripts` hook but as it `prints scripts in document head` i have doubt that i am not getting the time after full page load. i am not getting the correct time as body and footer content is yet to be executed/loaded.So i think i am getting the time it takes to load the head not the whole page.I can not use `wp_footer` and `shutdown` hooks because my page is cached.So how can i run my code to get the time after full page load without clearing/flushing the cache?
Here is my code:

**my-plugin.php**

```
function print_script() {

    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
        alert(loadTime);
        console.log(loadTime);
    }
            var var1 = <?php echo json_encode('var1'); ?>;
            var var2 = <?php echo json_encode('var2'); ?>;
            var var3 = <?php echo json_encode('var3'); ?>;

    </script>


  }
add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'print_script');
```

Comment: The browser dev tools should already be able to tell you this without making any changes to your site at all, perhaps you can provide some context to this as to why you need to get this in your themes code? What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: What to look in browser dev tool ? I need the page loading time of cached pages in my plugin.Due to cache necessary wordpress hooks  are inaccessible so i need to rely on pure javascript.My javascript in running in document head so i have doubt that i am not getting the correct time as body and footer content is yet to be executed/loaded.So i think i am getting the time it takes to load the head not the whole page.

Comment: Most caching plugins display the page generation time in a HTML comment in the footer, and you can see page generation times in a lot of analytics packages, e.g. Google Analytics. Also, if your page was cached, then the page generation time was zero, so it doesn't make sense to report this data for those pages

Comment: Your code should work fine... Open your dev-tools in Chrome (or similar) e.g. F12 or Cmd+F12. Refresh page. Observe load time shown in Chrome, then in your dev-tools console, copy and paste: `window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart;` this will show you can equivalent to what Chrome is showing.

Comment: As for dev tools, that depends on the browser you're using, Googling for that answer will give you far better results than I can, afterall I would need to google to make sure I give you a decent answer anyway, and then it'd be smushed into comments which would be suboptimal at best :/

Comment: See https://imgur.com/a/Qgi3hwu - and where applicable use different values on the `window.performance.timing` object if you want something other than `domContentLoadedEventEnd`

Comment: @TomJNowell you mean when the page is cached the html page is loaded in zero second? There is no time needed to load the html page contents ?

Comment: That would be network transfer time, which is not page generation time, it's important not to conflate the two. One is backend performance, the other is frontend performance, and the metric you were looking at in JS is some mixture of the two. Aside from WP hooks, I don't believe you've identified all of the specifics of the JS, such as where on the page it should happen and how it should be implemented, neither of which are WP questions

Comment: I mentioned in the question that currently i am running it in document head.My concern is to get a wp way to execute the script at end of a page.If the page was not cached i would easily use the shutdown hook.So i am looking for something alternative to wp_print_scripts, wp-footer or shutdown hook.

Comment: @Adam thank you so much for such a straight forward instruction.That was really helpful.Can you clear 1 more thing ?Does the placement(in the header or footer ) of window.onload matter ?I Mean if i place it in header then the loading time will be less than placing it in footer ?  Or ir will always be  the same ?

Comment: @query you can place it in the footer and the time should be the same as this calculation is from metrics that the browser records and exposes via the `performance` API. Since the code is not dependant on anything else I would enqueue it into the footer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should in this case use echo:

```
function print_script() {

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var loadTime = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart;
    alert(loadTime);
    console.log(loadTime);
}
        var var1 = <?php echo json_encode('var1'); ?>;
        var var2 = <?php echo json_encode('var2'); ?>;
        var var3 = <?php echo json_encode('var3'); ?>;

</script>';


}
 add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'print_script');
```